# DalekJs : Key code for the 'Enter' key with sendKeys

Tags: unicode, dalekjs

I am trying to simulate the **Enter** key like it is done with the **Escape** key in [this exemple](http://dalekjs.com/docs/actions.html#meth-sendKeys) :

```
test.open('http://home.dalek.com')
 .sendKeys('body', '\uE00C')
 .assert.dialogText('press the escape key give this alert text')
 .done();
```

I can't figure out what code should be used to simulate the Enter key.

Do you know a ressource listing the key codes that could be used with the *sendKeys* function ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's UTF-8 encoding, here you have the some handy [codes](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol#/session/%3asessionId/element/%3aid/value)

```
Return   U+E006
Enter    U+E007
```

Loads of literature available at [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [unicode-keymap](https://www.npmjs.org/package/unicode-keymap) NPM module to get an object with the entire character types mapping from the [W3C WebDriver spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webdriver-20120710/#character-types).

To install:

```
npm install unicode-keymap --save
```

To use:

```
var keys = require('unicode-keymap');
keys.Enter
// -> \uE007
```

Answer (score 0):

There's good character types table for `sendKeys` action in [W3C WebDriver spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-webdriver-20120710/#character-types).

Answer (score 0):

In Java you can do this also this way:

```
WebElement webElement;
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER)
webElement.sendKeys(Keys.Shift, "a")
```

...and so on.